# Simple access query with nested queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need some help with figuring out a query I am trying out from my textbook. I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated! 
The  query asks for PlayerNums who play the same slot machines at all casinos. I don't know how to approach this one.

Here's what I have so far, and trust me I'm aware that it is probably horribly
wrong.

```
SELECT P1.PlayerNum
FROM Plays as P1
WHERE P1.SlotNum IN
   (SELECT P2.SlotNum
    FROM Plays AS P2
    WHERE P2.CasinoNum IN
       (SELECT P3.CasinoNum
         FROM Plays AS P3));
```

Thanks for any help! Here are the tables: https://gyazo.com/a961956b95e04dde93e7dabbba215dcb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple SQL Query in access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939801/simple-sql-query-in-access)

Answer (score 0):

Base on your table structure, Try to join this 3 tables below...

```
    SELECT a.PlayerNum FROM Player a
    INNER JOIN Plays b ON a.PlayerNum = b.PlayerNum
    INNER JOIN Casino c ON b.CasinoNum = c.CasinoNum
```